# SQL Server : join select queries and update parameter

Tags: sql-server, select, join, parameters

I have the following queries

```
SELECT 
    CAST(practice_area_id AS int) AS Id
    ,name As Name
    ,CAST(0 AS bit) AS 'Selected'
FROM 
    practice_area
ORDER BY 
    name

SELECT 
    CAST (wt.work_type_id AS int) AS Id
    ,wt.name AS Name
    ,CASE wt.work_type_id 
        WHEN (SELECT wt.work_type_id 
              WHERE wt.work_type_id IN (SELECT CAST (mwt.work_type_id AS int) AS Id
                                        FROM matter_work_type mwt 
                                        LEFT JOIN work_type wt ON mwt.work_type_id = wt.work_type_id 
                                        WHERE mwt.matter_number = '00597959')) 
          THEN CAST(1 AS bit) 
        ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) 
    END AS 'Selected'
FROM 
    practice_area pa
JOIN 
    work_type_practice_area wtpa ON wtpa.practice_area_id = pa.practice_area_id
JOIN 
    work_type wt ON wt.work_type_id = wtpa.work_type_id
WHERE 
    pa.practice_area_id = 2
```

Here are the results

[image]

The first query returns all the root nodes for my tree list checkbox control. The second one returns all the childnodes for parent with id = 2

What I want to achieve is to replace `CAST(0 AS bit) AS 'Selected'` in the first query with value 1 only if there are selected children for this root node (at leas one record in the childnodes has Selected = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with nodes as (-- your second query)    
SELECT 
    CAST(practice_area_id AS int) AS Id,
    name As Name,
    case when exists(Select * from nodes where nodes.id = practice_area.id and selected=1) 
         then 1 
         else 0 end
from
    practice_area
ORDER BY 
    name
```